# Github action, cannot get timeout status from previous step

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm running some steps in a Gihub action and one of them can time out. The succeeding step should be able to check if the prior step failed with a time-out and only run in that case.

My job definition looks like this:

```
jobs:
  ...
  steps:
    - name: Run Spectacles Job
      id: spectaclesJob
      timeout-minutes: 1
      continue-on-error: true
      run: ...

    - name: Print conclusion
      run: echo ${{ steps.spectaclesJob.conclusion }}

    - name: Print outcome
      run: echo ${{ steps.spectaclesJob.outcome }}

    - name: Why does this step not run
      if: ${{ steps.spectaclesJob.conclusion == 'timeout' }}
      run: echo "And why is the conclusion 'success'"
```

I would expect the conclusion or the outcome of the prior step to be `timeout`. I can't rely on the `failure` outcome because it could also be a correct failure without hitting the timeout.

Here is a screenshot of my run: [image: screenshot of the run on Github]

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior when using [continue-on-error](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepscontinue-on-error) according to the [official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#steps-context):

| Property Name | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| steps.<step_id>.conclusion | string | The result of a completed step after [continue-on-error](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepscontinue-on-error) is applied. Possible values are `success`, `failure`, `cancelled`, or `skipped`. When a `continue-on-error` step fails, the outcome is `failure`, but the final conclusion is `success`. |

Unfortunately, according to the [status check functions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#status-check-functions), there is no way to identify if a step timed out or not at the moment on Github Actions, just if it failed, succeeded, was skipped or was cancelled.

*Note: A workaround could be to set an environment variable at the start of the execution step, then adding a step that calculates if the diff is longer than the timeout set.*